# Variation to singleton to return only 3 instances

Tags: algorithm, class, singleton, instance

I need to create a class which returns only 3 instances.The 4th request for an instance of this class should receive the 1st instance, 5th request receives the 2nd instance and so on in round robin fashion. Some code examples would be helpful.

Comment: Why the friggin' hell would you need anything like that? Stick to the [0-1-infinity rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
class Singelton{
    private static ArrayList<Singelton> singeltonList = new ArrayList<Singelton>();
    private static count = 0;
    public static Singelton getInstance(){
      if(singeltonList.size()<3)
        singeltonList.add(new Singelton());
      count = (count)%3;
      return singeltonList.get(count++);
    }
    private Singelton() {}
}
```

This solution is for java language.

Comment: I think it's better to store `count%3` in `count`, since current implementation will fail in case of overflow after big number of calls.